# SSAS anonymous access Cross Domain Access

Tags: sql, database, reporting, ssas

I'm trying to configure anonymous access to SSAS accross domains. Well at least that is what I think I need to do to solve my business problem.  I've attempted all the steps on here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324040

http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-faq/29-mgmt/2670-q-how-to-setup-ssas-anonymous-authentication-to-access-data-from-internet-or-another-domain

to no avail.

Let me explain my situation I've got a SQL Server running SSAS and then a development server with access to database server.  I would like a user that doesn't have access to SQL server box to be able to open Excel spreadsheets that connect to the SSAS server.  So they can browse the data.  I've found that the user on the development server also has to be the exact same user name and password on the SQL server.  This might not be the worst solution I was just wondering if anyone knew about a better way.

On another note being a bit of an SSAS newb what is the best way to expose a data cube on the web?  Any good resources for this would be very helpful.

If the user doesn't have credentials on the SSAS server I  get this error

"An error was encountered in the Transport Layer" Followed by this ever so informative error:

> Errors in the OLE DB provider. An error occurred while loading the
> connection dialog box component for prompting.

Thank you